# Why can't I modify the array outside of the .each method?

Tags: arrays, ruby, list

```rb
def adjacent_sum(arr)
  narr = []
  arr.each.with_index do  |num, index|
    narr << (arr[index] + arr[index+1])
  end
  return narr
end

print adjacent_sum([3, 7, 2, 11])
#=> [10, 9, 13], because [ 3+7, 7+2, 2+11 ]

adjacent_sum([2, 5, 1, 9, 2, 4])
#=> [7, 6, 10, 11, 6], because [2+5, 5+1, 1+9, 9+2, 2+4]
```

I am trying to modify the narr based on input from the user. Basically trying to get all adjacent nums to sum and return a new array.

***Write a method adjacent_sum that takes in an array of numbers and returns a new array containing the sums of adjacent numbers in the original array. See the examples.***

I am new to Ruby and its way of thinking. I do not know which iteration method to use for this problem and I know there are many iteration methods. I COULD go the old route and just do a while loop but I want to understand the mechanics of the .each loop.

Here is the error message:

```
/tmp/file.rb:5:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
    from /tmp/file.rb:5:in `block in adjacent_sum'
    from /tmp/file.rb:3:in `each'
    from /tmp/file.rb:3:in `with_index'
    from /tmp/file.rb:3:in `adjacent_sum'
    from /tmp/file.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you sure you have interpreted the statement of the problem in bold face correctly? Are the examples you give the ones referred to in that statement? If so, I would think that statement of the problem is poorly-worded, which of course is not your fault. Looking at your first example, `[3, 7, 2, 11]`, `3` has one adjacent element, `7`, so I would think the sum of the adjacent elements of `3` is `7`. `7` has two adjacent elements, `3` and `2`, whose sum is `5`, and so on, resulting in the desired array being `[7,5,18,2]`.

Comment: True. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop is iterating over every element of the list. Let's take your first example.

```
[3, 7, 2, 11]
```

Okay, we're iterating. First, we hit 3 (we're adding 7, because it's the next one). Next, we hit 7 (we're adding 2 to it). Third, we hit 2 (adding 11 to it). Finally, we hit 11, and what are we adding to it? We're adding `arr[4]`, which doesn't exist, hence your error.

`each` (and all of its *many* variants) fundamentally operate on the notion that you're taking *every* element of the underlying list. In your case, you want all but the last element, since you need to be able to add a "next" element in order to perform the addition. You *can* explicitly skip over the last element like so

```
arr.each.with_index do  |num, index|
  if index < arr.size - 1
    narr << (arr[index] + arr[index+1])
  end
end
```

but that's hardly better than a straight `while` loop. The point of all of Ruby's enumerable methods is choosing the right tool for the job, and in this case, Ruby's `Enumerable` has just the tool. [`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) gives you a sliding window of collection of N adjacent elements. So we can write

```
def adjacent_sum(arr)
  arr.each_cons(2).map { |x, y| x + y }
end
```

This is the power of Ruby's `Enumerable` module. Once you have a high-level construct that understands iteration, it provides a ton of tools for intelligently iterating over data structures, and *that's* why it's beneficial over a plain `while` loop.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think I have to disagree. The first of the OP's examples suggests that `[3, 7, 2, 11]` should produce `[10, 9, 13]`, which is (a) one element shorter than the original list, and (b) consistent with my answer as written.

Comment: I am guilty of not reading the question carefully. Please see my comment on the question.

Comment: Alternatively `arr.each_cons(2).map(&:sum)` (which also works for more than 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
def adjacent_sum(arr)
narr = []
l = arr.length
  
arr.each.with_index do  |num,index|
if index < arr.size-1
  narr << arr[index] + arr[index+1]
  end
end
return narr
end

print adjacent_sum([3, 7, 2, 11]) #=> [10, 9, 13], because [ 3+7, 7+2, 2+11 ]
puts
print adjacent_sum([2, 5, 1, 9, 2, 4]) #=> [7, 6, 10, 11, 6], because [2+5, 5+1, 1+9, 9+2, 2+4]
puts
```

I added the if conditional to make sure the array is not evaluated out of the index of the array and the code worked:
**if index < arr.size-1**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).